# Is it safer to use "ge" and "le" to get items created on specific dates using the REST API, rather than using "eq"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a custom list with field of type DateOnly named ExpiryDate:-

[image]

Here is the site regional settings:-

[image]

now i have noted if we change the ExpiryDate to accept Date-&-time then we change it back to Date-Only, the date stored in the SharePoint will have a time associate with it. so when we want to get items using the REST API with expiry date equal for example `2023-05-07` we will get wired results, because SharePoint will only search the items created at `2023-05-07T00:00:00Z`.. so is it safer to get the items using the Api query as follow: -

```
/items?$filter=(ExpiryDate ge '2023-05-07T00:00:00Z' and ExpiryDate le datetime'2023-05-07T23:59:59Z')
```

instead of:-

```
/items?$filter=(ExpiryDate eq '2023-05-07')
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with using 'ge' + 'le' instead of 'eq' is that you can get into max item per filter limit.

You can get a max of 5000 results for a single filter, once you have more than 5000 elements that match a given filter, the api will return an error.

For example, if you have more that 5000 elements which date is more than > 7/5/2023. If you try to use the following filter (ExpiryDate ge '2023-05-07T00:00:00Z' and ExpiryDate le datetime'2023-05-07T23:59:59Z') the api will crash because you have more than 5000 elements which match your first filter *ExpiryDate ge '2023-05-07T00:00:00Z*'.

But if you use the eq filter -> "DATEFIELD eq datetime'2023-05-07T00:00:00Z'". This will return all elements which are exactly on that day, since there are no more than 5000 elements which match that exact date.

You have to be careful with your filtered queries so your filters dont match more than 5000 results.

**Update:
I was wrong, GE + LE does work. If you have less than 5000 results between those two filters, results will return.**

Comment: thanks for the note which is very important. but i am doing the filter query inside the Power Automate GetItems do you know if i will face the same issue ?

Comment: now based on my test your comment on `ge` & `le` is not accurate. for example, i tried this query `$filter=ExpiryDate ge '2023-07-30'` i got this error `The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.`, but when i add the `and` as follow `ExpiryDate ge '2023-07-30' and ExpiryDate le '2023-08-02'` i got 100 results.. so if the first query exceeds 5000 this will not raise an error if we use `and`

Comment: Well, I retested what you told me and you are kind of right. My confussion came because SharePoints default date fields (Created and Modified) do produce this issues. Looks like you are free to use ge + le then!

Comment: yes correct your behavior will happen on the Modified date. do you know why this is happening on the modified date and not on the expiry date?

Comment: Because modified is the default SharePoint field and Expiry date is a custom indexed field. I guess the backend does not behave the same way for this type of requests.

Comment: this is another confusing point in SharePoint API especially for large lists